# How to access a saved image displayed on qlabel using pyqt5?

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt5, qlabel, qfiledialog

i design a user interface for browsing, and saving an image. i want the user to be able to save it in any desire folder, the read function works fine but the save function after saving the image i get an error on my IDE ( Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409) ),also i am unable to view the saved image from the folder. here is my code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
```

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(1314, 1327)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.Read_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.Read_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 140, 75, 23))
    self.Read_Button.setObjectName("Read_Button")
    self.Write_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.Write_Button.clicked.connect(self.saveFileDialog)
    self.Write_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 180, 75, 23))
    self.Write_Button.setObjectName("Write_Button")
self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    self.Read_Button.clicked.connect(self.setImage)
    #self.Write_Button.setEnabled(True)



def setImage(self):
    fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Read", "", "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *jpeg *.bmp);;All Files (*)") # Ask for file
    if fileName: # If the user gives a file
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(fileName) # Setup pixmap with the provided image
        pixmap = pixmap.scaled(self.imglabl.width(), self.imglabl.height(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio) # Scale pixmap
        self.imglabl.setPixmap(pixmap) # Set the pixmap onto the label
        self.imglabl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) # Align the label to center

def saveFileDialog(self, file_name):
    option=QFileDialog.Options()
    option|=QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog

    file= QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None, "Save", "", "All Files (*);;JPG Files (*.jpg);;PNG Files (*.png)" )

    if file[0]:
      print ("File saved as" + file)
if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Did you import `QFileDialog` separately? If not, you need to use `QtWidgets.QFileDialog`, like you did in the first method. (PS: always run your script in a standard command-window rather than an iDE to you can see the python traceback and/or qt messages. Or even better, configure your IDE so that it displays the output directly).

Comment: yes i did import qfiledialog, now i dont see the error but the problem is after saving the image, i can not see it in the selected folder, i only see it when i use the quick access on my computer ,Also when i try to view the image --it always blank

Comment: @Riscoky If you want further help, you must provide a [mre].

Comment: @ekhumoro, thank you for your response, i edited the code, you can check, i am a newbie in stackflow, i am not sure if i am providing the right information, I will appreciate if you can guide me further, this will help me improve better.

Comment: @Riscoky You say that there are problems when saving, but there's nothing in your example code that does that - it just prints the filename.

Comment: @ekhumuro please do you have an idea how I can implement this?

Comment: @Riscoky [QPixmap.save()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#save).

Comment: @ekhumoro.thank you for your feedback, I open the Qpixmap.save,the program is actually written in C, do you know how I can get in python